# Is built-in variable such as gl_Normal gl_Vertex supported by GLSL in OpenGL ES 2.0?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, shader

I am a fresher of OpenGL ES2.0 and GLSL, and I want to use shaders to process Images. When I coded in Xcode, I used built-in variables such as `gl_Normal`, `gl_Vertex` directly and did not declared them at the beginning of shaders. At last, I got a error message:

> Use of undeclared identifier `gl_Normal`. why?

Answer (score 5):

> Use of undeclared identifier gl_Normal. why?

In OpenGL-ES 2, and following in its footsteps OpenGL-3 core, there are no longer predefined shader input variables. OpenGL-4 did even away with predefined shader outputs.

Instead you're expected to define your own inputs and outputs. Each input or output variable as assigned a so called location. Either implicitly by OpenGL, and retrieveable by `glGetAttribLocation`, or explicitly by the programmer using the `location` storage qualifier attribute or `glBindAttribLocation` function. Outputs are similarily assigned by *fragment data locations*.

Comment: Technically, ES2 predates GL 3 by a pretty wide margin. It would be better to say that GL 3 is based on ES 2, but even that's incorrect.

Comment: @NicolBolas: IIRC OpenGL-3 and OpenGL-ES 2 were developed in parallel and it just took longer for OpenGL-3 to get finalized. After all things like compatibility profile and such had to be included into the spec as well.

Comment: That's not the history of OpenGL 3.0. The history of GL 3.0 goes through an effort called "Longs Peak", which was the code-name for an attempt at a complete rewrite of the OpenGL API. That rewrite attempt took 2 years, and it eventually [failed in early 2008](http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Main=47703&Number=243307#Post243307). ES 2.0 shipped in 2007. So it *cannot* be based on GL 3.0, because 3.0 was still Longs Peak with its new API.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Okay, I knew about Longs Peak, but I somehow had the (wrong) memory of it failing much earlier... anyway, I'm going to change my answer accoringly, thanks for the heads up.